# Are there redundant special methods on Python's built-in types?

Tags: python, built-in, magic-methods

In *Fluent Python* they say

> You write `len(my_object)` and, if `my_object` is an instance of a user-defined class, then Python calls the `__len__` instance method you implemented ...
>
> But for built-in types like `list`, `str`, `bytearray`, and so on, the interpreter takes a shortcut: the CPython implementation of `len()` actually returns the value of the `ob_size` field in the `PyVarObject` C struct that represent the any variable-sized built-in object in memory.

But `__len__` is still defined on at least some of these ...

```
>>> 'string'.__len__()
6
>>> [1, 2, 3].__len__()
3
```

What purpose do these methods serve if they're not called by `len`? And if are there other similar examples, what about them?

Comment: Subclassing is one case that springs to mind.

Comment: Python the *language* specifies that a type supporting the `len` protocol defines `__len__`. CPython the *implementation* can bypass it (since it is defining the built-in types itself anyway), but other implementations may choose to call `__len__` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the CPython implementation doesn't call `__len__()` by default doesn't meant that there aren't any Python libraries or user programs out there which do. Keeping the method available is about API stability, even if CPython takes shortcuts where possible.